# FileOutputStream into FileInputStream

Tags: java, file-io

What is the simplest way to convert a FileOutputStream into FileInputStream (a piece of code would be great)?

Comment: Do you even understand what you're asking for here?  What do you mean "convert"?  They are fundamentally opposite things; one is for reading and the other is for writing.  Are you trying to read the file you are writing to in your `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? A FileOutputStream writes to a file, and a FileInputStream reads from a file. I fail to see how the former could be converted into the latter.

Comment: I receive an FileOutputStream. What I want is read it.

Comment: @Pen: try this: `((FileInputStream)yourFileOutputStream)`, that would be the answer

Comment: You can't *read* from an *Output*Stream -- that's what *Input*Stream are for. You could try to use [`FileOutputStream.getChannel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#getChannel()) to get at the underlying file but that's not the usual way to do it.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart: absolutely. He'll get *expected* behavior.

Comment: @loki2302 Hrhr, that's one way to see it and would also give *exceptional* performance ;)

Answer (score 17):

This might help you:

http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html

This article mentions 3 possibilities:

- write the complete output into a byte array then read it again
- use pipes
- use a circular byte buffer (part of a library hosted on that page)

*Just for reference, doing it the other way round (input to output):*

A simple solution with Apache Commons IO would be:

```
IOUtils.copyLarge(InputStream, OutputStream)
```

or if you just want to copy a file:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(inFile,outFile);
```

If you don't want to use Apache Commons IO, here's what the `copyLarge` method does:

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException 
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  long count = 0L;
  int n = 0;
  while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
   output.write(buffer, 0, n);
   count += n;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: The link is broken, but you can still find the original answer here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110929161214/http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html

Answer (score 4):

> I receive an FileOutputStream. What I want is read it.

You certainly can't read from an `OutputStream`.  I think you mean you want to read from the file being written to by the `FileOutputStream`.  I don't think you can do that either.  The `FileOutputStream` doesn't seem to keep a reference to the file being written to.

What you need to do is discover what `File` or path (a `String`) was passed into the `FileOutputStream` and use that same `File` or `String` to create a new `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I think he could use FileOutputStream.getFD() to get the FileDescriptor; than build a FileInputStream around it. Not sure if you can simultaneously read and write from the same FileDescriptor though.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Good point, I had actually looked into that but missed the fact that `FileInputStream` has a constructor that takes a `FileDescriptor`.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you want to be able to read the contents after writing (without flushing to disk), use a ByteArrayOutputStream and a ByteArrayInputStream. Once you're done writing to the ByteArrayOutputStream, you can get the underlying byte data and use a ByteArrayInputStream to read it back.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// do any output onto outStream you need
ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());
// you can read back the output with inStream now
```

If you want a buffer (producer/consumer type problem), look into the Buffers provided with java's nio package.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use @Thomas example given, otherwise you can do:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FileInputOutputExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("in.txt");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
    int c;
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
      System.out.print((char) c);
      os.write(c);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();

  }
}
```

example from java2s.com

EDIT:

As @Thomas deleted his answer, I will just add for reference Commons IO approach for handling this:

```
IOUtils.copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is "converting a `FileOutputStream` into a `FileInputStream`."

Comment: Actually my example was the other way round (input to output), so I deleted it. If it is still relevant, I could undelete it for reference.

Comment: @Mark: that's true, I just assumed he wants to read one into the other

Comment: I preferred the now deleted answer with Commons IO over this. It lacks correct resource handling (try-finally) and does unbuffered single-byte copying.

Comment: @Philip: me too :), as 'Thomas' deleted his answer I just added this way below mine

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a RandomAccessFile.  This has the same basic methods of both the FileInputStream and a FileOutputStream.  I know, you probably aren't given that.