# Convert the Bitmap image into File and pass to the FileInputStream?

Tags: java, android

This is my code for converting bitmap to byte array.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
 byte[] bitmapdata = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

And, I want to pass that array to the `FileInputStream`. And `FileInputStream` only accepts `File`. So I created the `byte` array to file using `FileOutputStream`. But `FileInputStream` did not accepting the `File` from `FileOutputStream`. I am new to Android coding.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant potion of your Android code as well?

Comment: IMO, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610926/fileoutputstream-into-fileinputstream

Comment: From where you are picking up your image?

Answer (score 1):

Try This its work fine...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
 byte[] bitmapdata = outputStream.toByteArray();
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
```

Comment: Thanks @neeraj-singh for your answer. My interface only accepts `FileInputStream`. Is there any way to do that.